# The time for each epoch in my neural network is 0 sec

Tags: neural-network

While running my model,the time for each epoch is 0 sec, does that mean there is something wrong with my model[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6x1vk.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably training is just fast.

These epoch times are very possible when using GPU's. Of course, only on smaller datasets/architectures.

Say you are training MNIST with fairly straightforward network (LeNet alike CNN), these times are pretty normal.

From scanning the loss/acc, something is happening as the numbers are not constant.

Comment: Agree. The loss is decreasing and the accuracy is increasing, which is what you want. If you significantly increase your dataset and you are still seeing this, that might be cause for concern